# Calling reverse-router with a default variable

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

In my router I have

```
GET    /:namespace/:name    controllers.Application.page_view(namespace: String, name: String, redirect:Boolean ?= true)
```

In the URL I can do `/main/home` or `/main/name?redirect=0` if I want something other than the default value. I would like to do something similar with a call to the reverse-router, but for example: `return redirect(routes.Application.page_view("main", "home"));` *doesn't work* ... I need to include a 'true' in there too (the default), is is possible to make the call without stating the optional variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible in Java's reverse routes arguments or views arguments - you need to specify default value in controller:

```
return redirect(routes.Application.page_view("main", "home", true));
```

On the other hand in Scala driven views you can do that as you want, compare:

```
<pre>
    @(routes.Application.page_view("one", "two"))
    @(routes.Application.page_view("three", "four", true))
    @(routes.Application.page_view("five", "six", false))
</pre>
```

### Edit

As you pointed yourself it's also possible to *overload* your action (but note it's not overloading sensu stricto as for route resolver you will need to use other name), as:

`routes`:

```
GET     /:namespace/:name     controllers.Application.pageViewDefault(namespace: String, name: String)
GET     /:namespace/:name     controllers.Application.pageView(namespace: String, name: String, redirect: Boolean ?= true)
```

`Controller`:

```
public static Result pageViewDefault(String namespace, String name) {
    return pageView(namespace, name, true);
}

public static Result pageView(String namespace, String name, boolean redirect) {
   if (redirect) //return some redirect...
   // in other case return a Result...
}
```

**Anyway** I can tell you from my experience, that on longer run it will be uncomfortable for you: you will need to remember each time (both in the controller and in the view) that if you should at the moment choose `pageView` or `pageViewDefault`. IMHO it's better, just use single action and remember to add default redirect where required - `pageView(ns, n, true)` vs `pageView(ns, n, false)`.

Also with your approach you will need to remember about `*Default` action in the view, while with single action you will not:

```
<pre>
    @(routes.Application.pageViewDefault("one", "two"))
    @(routes.Application.pageView("three", "four", false))

    vs.
    @(routes.Application.pageView("one", "two"))
    @(routes.Application.pageView("three", "four", false))
</pre>
```

To make life simpler just declare constant in your controller:

```
private static final boolean DEFAULT_REDIRECT = true;
```

So you can use that later for default routes:

return redirect(routes.Application.pageView("main", "home", DEFAULT_REDIRECT));

Also if you will have a lot of actions with optional `redirect` argument for each you will need to create `*Default` action + dedicated route.

Comment: I found a work-around by the way (probably not to be recommended) , if I add in the router below the original statement - `/:namespace/:name    controllers.Application.page_view_default(namespace: String, name: String)` (where /:namespace/:name is a duplicate, and page_view_default is declared in the controller, but without expecting it to do anything specific) I can call the reverse router, and it will direct to the default value

Comment: Thanks for the generous explanation - decided to go with the single declaration in the `routes` (and switch to Scala later!)

Comment: Note: reverse routes shouldn't force you to switch from Java to Scala. If you're Java geek, stay at Java, samples about Scala views are the same for both: Java and Scala version as view are built always with Scala, so you can ommit there some default params while building the route.